# Trying to fetch data from a remotely-hosted MySQL database, using React Native

Tags: mysql, node.js, react-native, linode

I am trying to create a React Native app that can access and display movie showtime data from a MySQL database that I have stored on linode. I have a server.js file set up that looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '<host ip>',
  user: '<user>',
  password: '<password>',
  database: 'filmscrapedb',
});

const app = express();

app.get('/FilmShowings', function (req, res) {
  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM FilmShowings', function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(results);
  });

  connection.end();
});
// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Go to http://localhost:3000/FilmShowings to see FilmShowings');
});
```

Running this, I can see my data at the localhost address:

```
[{"title":"The Night of the Hunter","showtime":"5:00 pm","date":"Sep 9","location":"Row House Cinema","buy_ticket_link":"https://rowhousecinema.com/purchase/344799/","summary":"Based on a true story out of nearby Clarksburg, West Virginia, this Robert Mitchum noir is a nightmarish fairytale thriller about a serial killing preacher in the deep south. Mitchum keeps you on the edge of your seat as he hunts two young children who know the location of a stash of money hidden by their real father."}
...etc
```

However, I am stumped on how to fetch this data into React Native. I have attempted to adapt the function component example from [React Native's docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network), like so:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/FilmShowings');
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json.FilmShowings);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 24}}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Text>
              {item.title}, {item.location}
            </Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

...but this is clearly incorrect, as I am getting an error of  `[TypeError: Network request failed]`. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up CORS on your server? Most of the time your requests fails because server rejects a request from an unknown source. If you try your logic inside a react app and check developer tool in the browser, you may see the exact error. Your code looks good me!!

Comment: What's the IP of your server? Try requesting that IP instead of **localhost**. For example, http://20.0.1.1:3000/FilmShowings

Comment: @Ammar - I'm getting the same error when using the IP of my server

Comment: Can you debug your network request inside react-native and see if you are hitting the right address?

Comment: @Sanish Joseph, I tried running the logic in a react app, I'm getting an error of `Fetch API cannot load localhost:3000/FilmShowings. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.`. When I tried running the react app with my server's IP instead of localhost, the error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Looks like you missed `http://` in your API URL

Comment: @Sanish Joseph, on adding `http://` to the url, I am getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: Is your local API running?