# How to sync data between desktop and mobile app?

Tags: sql, reactjs, react-native, api, electron

I built a desktop application with `Electron JS`, `SQLite`, and `React JS`.

The desktop app allows an admin to add, delete and retrieve clients and it's connected to a `SQLite` database that stores client information. It uses SQL queries to perform these operations:

```
 //Add a client to the db
exports.addClient = (client) => {
  db.prepare(
    "INSERT INTO clients (name, phone , position, description) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
  ).run(clients.name, clients.phone, clients.position, clients.description);
};
```

As you can see, I am not creating any REST APIs in here.

Now I want to build a mobile app but for the clients (with `React Native`), and it should be able to display clients information that are stored in the DB.

My question is how do I connect the mobile app to the database to fetch the data of clients? Do I write SQL queries like I did in the desktop app or do I have to create REST APIs and then fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps indeed use the same database(s) as a desktop app so that any changes in the database records whether on mobile or desktop is reflected on all connected devices.

For your problem (and correct me if I'm wrong), I believe you are try to connect a mobile app to a database hosted on the same machine as your desktop application. If so then you would need to create a connection to your database using a public ip address.

[Here's a drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOBsz.png)

The downside to this method is that since your database will be publicly accessible, it will be vulnerable to a denial of service attacks, furthermore, your client(s) are talking to the database directly which makes scaling an issue. If you're not worried about these types of problems, or are creating doing this just for learning then I don't see any problem with directly connecting to the database.

With APIs, you can have a common interface for all your devices to interact with. Your desktop and mobile app can connect to the API and then the API can directly communicate with your database. This will allow you to move common CRUD functions from both your apps over to the API. It also makes scaling easier if your plan to add more devices in the future.

As for how to code data fetching function in react native, I think these posts might help:

[Trying to fetch data from a remotely-hosted MySQL database, using React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122824/trying-to-fetch-data-from-a-remotely-hosted-mysql-database-using-react-native)
https://dev.to/saulojoab/how-to-get-data-from-an-mysql-database-in-react-native-53a4

Comment: If I use APIs in my application, I would have to create them in NodeJS which uses Electron as a back-end. But Electron is used for building desktop apps and I don't think I can create APIs with it. What would I have to do in that case to create the APIs?

Comment: I heavily edited my question, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Excellent, Now it's much clearer and to answer your question: No you don't need a seperate REST API as long as you can make a connection to your database over the internet and send HTTP requests (GET, POST, etc). The two websites I referenced in my post demonstrate that by making a simple GET request to the database with the SQL query. Now I don't use React but I'm sure you can't use the same function as you wrote in the desktop app as it's not a HTTP request but you should be able to use the same SQL query maybe with slight modifications to the syntax depending on how React Native handles it.